# Spawn Powershell from Javascript WITHOUT Node.js

Tags: javascript, powershell

I'm trying to run a small PowerShell script ***from*** JavaScript, upon a button click.

***NOTES:***

1. My account is a regular user account
2. No additional libraries/software/modules/etc can nor will be installed
3. I have no access to Python, PHP - just Java, javascript, powershell and not much more
4. There have been some new security "upgrades" over the past few weeks

Here's the JavaScript snippet with the call/execute of the PowerShell script:

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     let submitButton = document.getElementsByClassName('submit-button');
     if (value1.value.length == 0 || value2.value.length == 0 || value3.value.length == 0) {
          event.preventDefault();
      } else {
          submitForm();
   // Add Call For PowerShell
           var spawn = require("child_proc").spawn;
           spawn("powershell.exe",["myScript.ps1"]);
       }
  })
```

When I initially put the *var spawn ...* into the script, I did not realize that Node.js was required. Is there another way to execute a PowerShell script without Node.js?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - and if there was then those _security "upgrades"_ were just _security upgrades_ because it should not be possible.

Comment: You can use Deno, Rhino or a similar JavaScript engine. If you want to use your browser, you can write a browser extension.

Comment: @Slbox - thanks, most of the results from searching point to a one word answer, No.

Comment: @jabaa - that would be great, but our browsers are managed by admins; seriously doubt using other engines is possible, but I'll try. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `spawn` method, from `child_process` API, only exists on NodeJS.

You can see the method references [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options).

Also, you can look at the browser available APIs in the [MDN APIs reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API).

##### Optional Solution

You can open a http server on your machine, and send an http request to that server with the script that you want to run and from that you execute the script.

##### TL;DR

You can't execute OS level scripts from your browser for security reasons. You will need something running direct on your machine to do this job.

Comment: "*You can open a http server on your machine, and send an http request to that server with the script that you want to run and from that you execute the script*" running **arbitrary user-supplied code** is not something I'd call a "solution" but rather a "problem".

Comment: @Matheus Almeida - this cannot be done with the architecture we have here. Thanks anyway. For me/here, what I'd like to do most likely cannot be done.